# JSON_decode with file_get_contents, why is not working?

Tags: php, json, joomla

I use the following simple code to calculate a copper price in my website.

```
<?php 

$copper_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/LME/PR_CU.json?limit=1&api_key=XXXXXXX'), true);
$currency_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=XXXXXXX'), true);
$copper_lv_per_ton = $copper_data['dataset']['data'][0][2]*$currency_data['rates']['BGN'];

?>
```

The code works just fine in a static php page, but when included in Joomla article (via plugin called [Sourcerer](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer/features)) it does not work

Comment: Why not post at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange? You already have an account there.

Comment: It is not a Joomla problem actually ... I should change the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that **allow_url_fopen** was disabled in php.ini or php73-fcgi.ini **allow_url_fopen = 1 (or On)**

In my server there are many files php73-fcgi.ini, php72-fcgi.ini and more...
In all of them I found this **allow_url_fopen** and enabled it (set to 1 or On) then it worked.

Be careful because the change took 10-15 minutes in my case. I believe because of caching ..